# How to solve the error SIGABRT even if the outlets look correct?

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

I'm working on my first iOS app with `Xcode` and `Swift`. My app has multiple `UIViewController`s (=VC). Everything works quite well, but there is an error which I couldn't work out on my own with the help of Google or StackOverflow.

My problem is:

I have a `UIButton` called 'Quit' in the VC 'CompleteTest' which I control dragged in the `Main` storyboard to the VC 'Main Menu' in order that it brings the user back to the 'Main Menu' when it is pressed. 
But when I click this `UIButton` in the Simulator the error:

> Thread 1 signal SIGABRT comes up.

This is not the first time I stumbled over this error and I saw multiple threads in stack overflow giving a solution to this problem. In the past by checking the outlets I could solve this error quite easily.
But in this case this solution doesn't work, because the outlets look fine (there are no exclamation-points showed).

What is even more strange is where the error is showed.
Normally the `SIGABRT` error is shown in the `AppDelegate`, if I'm not mistaken. 
But in my case it is shown at the line 54 of the VC 'CompleteTest'-file. At this line I am transferring data to the next VC 'Final Complete test' with the override function 'prerpare'.

Unfortunately, I couldn't put images in this question, even tough
I prepared them. Anyway I hope my problem is still clear.

Furthermore, excuse me for my poor English as it is my second language.

How should I proceed? Thank you in advance for your help!

```
import UIKit

class CompleteTest: UIViewController {

    // Components of Visualisation VC
    @IBOutlet weak var ShotNumber: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProjectedScore: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Distance: UILabel!

    var sum: Double = 100.0     //sum represents overall Score of Test

    @IBOutlet weak var Report: UIButton!

    var help: Int = 0           // var 'help' is helping to change the number showed on the Scoring Buttons in VC

    @IBOutlet weak var Left1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var Right1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var Center1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var BadContact1: UIButton!



    //Percentage components
    var leftpct: Int = 0

    var rightpct: Int = 0

    var centerpct: Int = 0

    var totalpct: Int = 0

    var badcontactpct: Int = 0




    // Transfer of data from ViewController 'CompleteTest' to ViewController 'FinalCompleteTest'
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let finalCompleteTest = segue.destination as! FinalCompleteTest
        finalCompleteTest.score = String(sum)
        finalCompleteTest.Leftpct = Int(leftpct)
        finalCompleteTest.Rightpct = Int(rightpct)
        finalCompleteTest.Centerpct = Int(centerpct)
        finalCompleteTest.Totalpct = Int(totalpct)
        finalCompleteTest.BadContactpct = Int(badcontactpct)

}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Report.isHidden = true
    }


    //Scoring Buttons

    @IBAction func BadContact(_ sender: Any) {
        sum -= 1
        BadContact1.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        badcontactpct += 1

    }

    @IBAction func Left(_ sender: Any) {
        sum -= 0.5
        help += 1
        Left1.setTitle(String(help), for: .normal)
        if help == 1 {
        leftpct += 1
            totalpct += 1}
    }

    @IBAction func Right(_ sender: Any) {
        sum -= 0.5
        help += 1
        Right1.setTitle(String(help), for: .normal)
        if help == 1 {
        rightpct += 1
            totalpct += 1}
    }

    @IBAction func Center(_ sender: Any) {
        Center1.setTitle("0", for: .normal)
        centerpct += 1
            totalpct += 1

    }
```

Comment: You have an exclamation mark in `let finalCompleteTest = segue.destination as! FinalCompleteTest`. So you crash if the VC in the storyboard is the wrong class.

Comment: Full error message in console? Also, avoid naming your var & methods starting with an uppercase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough question. If you want, you can upload your images to some other site (e.g. [imgur](http://imgur.com/)) and then use the direct links here.

As [matt mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059543/how-to-solve-the-error-sigabrt-even-if-the-outlets-look-correct#comment98759601_56059543), that `as!` might be the reason you're seeing this crash. You can easily prove it if you replace your code to something like this:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let finalCompleteTest = segue.destination as? FinalCompleteTest {
            finalCompleteTest.score = String(sum)
            finalCompleteTest.Leftpct = Int(leftpct)
            finalCompleteTest.Rightpct = Int(rightpct)
            finalCompleteTest.Centerpct = Int(centerpct)
            finalCompleteTest.Totalpct = Int(totalpct)
            finalCompleteTest.BadContactpct = Int(badcontactpct)
        } else {
            print("oh no, segue.destination is not a FinalCompleteTest")
        }
    }
```

If you can see that message in your console, probably you haven't connected something correctly on the storyboard.

If not, try to give us some more information.

If you don't understand the "dangers" of using `!` in your code, please try to understand [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) first and don't hesitate to ask if you need more help.

Good luck!

Comment: In this particular case this syntax provides no benefit at all. Instead of the crash you see "Oh no" and the segue doesn't work anyway. There are only two reasons for a failure: The identifier doesn't match or the class name doesn't match. If everything is hooked up correctly the forced downcast must not crash.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My point was to help him understand the underlying problem himself - of course I know my answer won't fix the crash but I was hoping to drive him to the right direction.

Comment: This is all good advice but I don’t think any of it is an answer. If you want to chat with the OP and steer him towards better testing if the issue, that’s for comments.

Comment: Probably, I used the easy fix to my problem in replacing the "!" with a "?" in this line of code. ----> if let finalCompleteTest = segue.destination as? FinalCompleteTest {          -But the error SIGABRT vanished and my app works now as a consequence. Next up, I will surely look up how optionals work exactly. Where do I find good tutorials for free for Swift. I know that there are many free tutorials on YouTube, but some of them are probably trash. I still  have a long way to go. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JeremyLocher If the destination controller is supposed to be `FinalCompleteTest` then adding the optional binding causes the "Oh no" output and the `pct` values are not transferred. So the code cannot work as expected.